# Drools Collection Iteration

Tags: drools, business-rules

what's Wrong with this rule.

```
rule "Organization Employee Rule"
    when

        $company: CompanyFact( $emp: /employeeList{organizationName== "XYZ"})

    then
        System.out.println("Employee in organization" +$emp);
end
```

I am getting this error while trying to run this rule.

**[ERR 102] Line 23:44 mismatched input '{' in rule "Organization Employee Rule"**

CompanyFact has list of Employee and Employee has String organization name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Drools 7.x, they [changed the OOPath syntax to make it closer to XPath](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_oopath_improvements).

Try to use square brackets instead of curly ones:

```
rule "Organization Employee Rule"
when
    $company: CompanyFact( $emp: /employeeList[organizationName== "XYZ"])
then
    System.out.println("Employee in organization" +$emp);
end
```

Hope it helps,